# Itunes Connect display issue

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, displayobject

Can anyone tell me why my iTunes connect looks like this and how to fix it?
Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you. (see image)

it is displaying the object name instead of what the object actually is meant to look like, for example it says

```
ITC.AppVersion.Actionbutton.SaveButton
```

instead of saying `save`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself. I suspect it had something to do with the transition to the iOS 11 App Store.